# Unable to update calendar event: bad request

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to update a calendar event in a google calendar. My code is currently as follows:

```
function changeVisibilityForTwoWeeks() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var now = new Date();
  var inTwoWeeks = new Date();
  inTwoWeeks.setDate(new Date().getDate()+14);


  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    timeMax: inTwoWeeks.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  });
  if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
      var event = events.items[i];
        if (event.organizer.email.endsWith("@somedomain.com"))
        ) {
          event.setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PRIVATE); 
          event = Calendar.Events.update(event, calendarId, event.getId());
        }
  }} 
}
```

All I get is **GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.update failed with error: Bad Request**

Any suggestions where I'm wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to update an event using [Calendar.Events.update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update), you passed a complete [Events resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) as your request body.

Please take note that not all parameters in [Events resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) are writable when using [Calendar.Events.update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update). Refer to the list of required and optional properties that could be modified/updated using [Calendar.Events.update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) method in the [Request body](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#request-body):

**(Incomplete List)**
[image]

**Sample Code:**

```
if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
      var event = events.items[i];
        if (event.organizer.email.endsWith("@somedomain.com"))
        {
          var updateEvent = {
            start: {
              dateTime: event.start.dateTime
            },
            end: {
              dateTime: event.end.dateTime
            },
            visibility: "private"
          };
          
          Logger.log(updateEvent);
          event = Calendar.Events.update(updateEvent, calendarId, event.getId());
        }
  }}
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

---

### IMPORTANT NOTE:

I purposely did not include other optional parameters to show you that if you did not copy other parameters in your old event to your updated event, It will still be updated when you used [Calendar.Events.update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update). Notice that the title was not set.

Therefore, please make sure to copy necessary information/properties from your old event to your updated event and make sure it is writable based on the Calendar.Events.update [Request body](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#request-body)

---

### Alternative Option:

As mentioned by OP in the comment section, you can use [Calendar.Events.patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) to update your desired properties. Fields that you don’t specify in the request remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I didn't find that piece of documentation... Thanks for the input. Btw, I'm decided to use patch instead of update to prevent overwriting properties.

Comment: Great idea, sorry I wasn't able to check that part :). I just focused on what you are currently working on. I gained a new knowledge today as well thanks

Comment: By the way, let me update my answer with your solution as reference to other users that might missed the comment section